# Laravel 5.1 Registration flash message - Auth

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

How to display a flash message on built in laravel 5.1 authentication after registration?

Comment: try this package: https://github.com/digitlimit/alert

Answer (score 0):

Just go to \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers

Add this below:

> $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Registration
>   successful');

RegistersUsers.php

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Registration successful');

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

and in your HTML Blade page, add these codes

```
@foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
    <div class="flash-message">
       <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }} <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a></p>
    </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I think this is not an elegant solution but it works for me, hope this helps you.

Comment: Since RegistersUsers.php is a trait that's included in RegisterController.php, you'd want to copy the postRegister method into RegisterController, to override the trait's method. Otherwise your changes are inside a dependency and will be lost when you update dependencies.